# Phonegap Android: where does the application data saves? Is it possible to move to the SD card?

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing an Android app in Phonegap, and I have a large number of files to save. I was looking for the best storage option in Phonegap. For that I need to know if I use LocalStorage or an sqlite database for my app, where will the app data be saved? I think it will be saved in internal memory. If so how to move that to the SD card?

Answer (score 1):

You can save it using the file system. [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File)

I do not know if you can access the SD card, too. It might be different depending on your device.

You can also use the local storage function of HTML5, which is browser data and only the your device as far as i know.

Comment: If I use the localstorage / sqllite , where does all this data go to? To phone memory or sd card?

Comment: I used sqlite on the ipad so far. safari saves the data on the device. you actually delete the entries, when you clear all browser data. So I would look more into using the file system. There is a way on Android to move apps from the device to SD cards: eg. App2SD (it is an app you find in the market place). Something you may look into to experiment with.

Answer (score 0):

It will be stored in the SD card. You can see it in the "mnt/sdcard/" folder of your emulator.